# mutiple data in a linked list?

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm currently working on my assignment. 
The assignment question stated:
"Get input from the user regarding a delivery record which consists of the delivery record id, the supplier name, the order date, the delivery date, the quantity of each type of paper, and a status indicating whether delivered, pending, or cancelled."

"You are to implement a linked-list class to keep the delivery records."

How do I keep multiple data in a linked-list class? Do I keep multiple data in each node?
Like this:

```
struct node
{
char id[10];
char name[20];
char orderDate[20];
char deliveryDate[20];
int quantity;
char status[10];

node *next;
};
```

will this work?

*EDITED*
So my class would be like this?

```
class linkedlist{
   //public functions
   private:
   struct node;
   typedef node* nodeptr;
   struct node
   {
   char id[10];
   char name[20];
   char orderDate[20];
   char deliveryDate[20];
   int quantity;
   char status[10];

   node *next;
   };
```

};

correct?

Comment: I do not fully understand what you are asking about but you probably would each node for each delivery record. In such case each delivery record would only contain its ID and its data and would link to the next node representing another delivery.

Comment: Yes, what you have there will work fine.

Comment: It was better before the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Paul92 regarding the datatypes you choose.

It is also good practice to separate the nodes' data from the storage structure. Your struct is called node and contains info about the delivery record as well as a pointer to the next devilvery record. A cleaner implementation with separation of concerns using composition could look like

```
struct DeliveryRecord {
    char id[10];
    char name[20];
    char orderDate[20];
    char deliveryDate[20];
    int quantity;
    char status[10];
};

template<typename T>
struct ListNode {
    T data;
    ListNode* next;
};
```

and if you prefer inheritence you could use a ListNode class like

```
template<typename T>
struct ListNode : public T {
    ListNode* next;
};
typedef ListNode<DeliveryRecord> DeliveryRecordListNode;
```

This way the way you store the records may vary without changing the look and feel of the record struct. Next assignment might say that you should store them in a tree structure. That won't change the DeliveryRecord struct. You will just have to create a TreeNode class template ;-)

Comment: for your answer above, how do i access each members in the struct?

Comment: If you're using the composition kind you have a ListNode<DeliveryRecord>* record; char* name = record->data.name;

With the inheritence kind you just go char* name = record->name; since the DeliveryRecord class is a base of ListNode<DeliveryRecord>.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are on the right track putting multiple data in each node, but I have some mentions to your node structure:

1. If the id is a numerical value, it should be an integer data type, like int.
2. As dates are a little bit hard to handle and parse as string, I would use a date structure:

   > ```
   > struct date{
   >     int day;
   >     int month;
   >     int year;
   > };
   > ```
3. Also, status should be bool, and a more appropiate name would be delivery. In this case, a true value for delivery variable would mean that it has been delivered, and a false value would mean pending.
4. Make sure that 20 characters are enough for supplier name.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah..You can also write class and mention this all information as data members in that class. Once you wrote class you can make object of your class and use this object as one node in link list. Is your requirement in c++ or c?